# Problema al hacer git push

Tags: git, github

Estoy tratando de actualizar un proyecto ya subido a `Github` pero me salen los siguientes errores:

[image: Errores]

Todo sucede luego de realizar los siguientes comandos:

```
$ git add . 

$ git commit -m "equis"

$ git status
```

Pero luego al realizar:

```
$ git push
```

Es que me indica los errores de la imagen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te esta pidiendo que hagas git pull para obtener los cambios del servidor, haces el git pull obtienes los cambios en tu repositorio local de tu maquina y ya te permitirá hacer el push

Answer (score 0):

Antes de subir un cambio siempre debes descargar los cambios del repositorio, atravez del comando git pull, si no hay conflictos procedes a

```
$ git add . 

$ git commit -m "equis"

$ git status

git push
```